# How i can used meta in nested nested json in Python

Tags: python, json

I need to find information in a json url.
I used this code for opening the url:

```
link = 'https://cordis.europa.eu/search/fr?q=contenttype%3D%27project%27%20AND%20programme%2Fcode%3D%27H2020%27&p=1&num=10&srt=/project/contentUpdateDate:decreasing&format=json'
r = requests.get(link)
```

This one for beeing in the first nested:

```
pd.json_normalize(r.json(),record_path=['hits','hit'])
```

An this one for beeing in the level I need:

```
pd.json_normalize(r.json(),record_path=['hits','hit','project','relations','associations','organization'])
```

Until here it's ok (maybe there is something simpler but it's ok)

The difficulty is know for me.
I don't understand completly the 'meta' methode.
I wan't to have the id from the top level : 'project.id'

I tried this but I have an error:

```
pd.json_normalize(r.json(),record_path=['hits','hit','project','relations','associations','organization'], meta = ['project.id'])
```

He can't find the name 'project.id'.
Do you have an ID?

Answer (score 0):

Does this solve your problem?

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

def get_project_ids():
    link = 'https://cordis.europa.eu/search/fr?q=contenttype%3D%27project%27%20AND%20programme%2Fcode%3D%27H2020%27&p=1&num=10&srt=/project/contentUpdateDate:decreasing&format=json'
    r = requests.get(link)

    df = pd.json_normalize(r.json(), record_path=['hits', 'hit', 'project', 'relations', 'associations', 'organization'])
    return df['id'].tolist()
    
print(get_project_ids())
```

Comment: Sorry I made an error in my question. I have th id but i need to saee him when I am in the lower level.

Comment: I edited my answer. When you print the df you see the "id" in the lower level. If you only use `df = pd.json_normalize(r.json(), record_path=['hits', 'hit'])` column name will be "project.id"